# How to access private variables using functions only

Tags: c++, encapsulation

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    asksUser();
    printLarger(int, int);
    return 0;
}

int asksUser()
{
    int num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num2;
    return num1;
    return num2;
}

int printLarger(int num1, int num2)
{
 //Will compare the two ints and print out biggest

}
```

So I had a simple problem which I could've quite easily just done in main but I thought, why not try and do how I've been taught in Clean Code and split everything into tiny functions. Granted both my functions still do two things which isn't what they preferred... Turns out it wasn't as simple as I thought.

Comment: You can have two ``return``'s but only the first one will return.

Comment: asksUser should request and return ONE number, and be called TWICE from main. Plus where do you store the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return twice, but you don't have to: one purpose behind writing a function in the first place is reusing its logic.

You can write a function `askUser` that returns an `int`, and call it twice from the main, like this:

```
int a = askUser();
int b = askUser();
printLarger(a, b);
```

Comment: I prefer your way of doing it to Cyber but very interesting how there are so many ways to approach one problem.

Comment: @user3255112 "very interesting how there are so many ways to approach one problem" To me, this observation captures the beauty of programming :-) Each programming problem has a large number of solutions. At first, building a working solution is a challenge, but eventually you start picking solutions that are shorter, easier to read, easier to debug, and so on.

Comment: I agree and what's more wonderful is that everyone I've been answered by clearly really wants to solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two return statements in a row like that, only the first will be returned, the second will never execute.

You could break up the logic as follows (though the function names are a bit misleading now).

```
int main()
{
    int larger = asksUser();
    cout << "Larger number is: " << larger << endl;
    return 0;
}

int asksUser()
{
    int num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> num2;

    return printLarger(num1, num2);
}

int printLarger(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

**Edit**
To re-write the `printLarger` function without a [ternary expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx), the same idea would be:

```
int printLarger(int num1, int num2)
{
    if (num1 > num2)
        return num1;
    else
        return num2;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks I guessed that the two returns weren't the legit way of returning. By the way what does: num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2; mean? I was going to use if statements but it seems yours is much more efficient.

Comment: See my edit regarding the ternary expression. As far as your compiler is concerned, they will likely produce the same assembly code, I just prefer the ternary since it is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can only return from a function once, as the second call to return will never be reached. You could split these two calls up so that you call the function askUser twice or in the C++11 standard you can return tuples:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<const int , const int> asksUser ( const int * numbers , const int num ) {
    int number1, number2;
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter number ";
    cin >> number2;

    return std::make_tuple( *number1 , *number ) ;
}

int printLarger(std::tuple<const int , const int> result)
{
    /*
     * Will compare the two ints and print out biggest
     * std::get<0>(result) will contain number1
     * std::get<0>(result) will contain number2
     */
}

int main( ) {
    std::tuple<const int , const int> result = asksUser() ;
    printLarger( result ) 
    return 0 ;
}
```

But why are you trying to separate into small function? Most of the time it's so that you can reuse the code block in other places. A function to take two number from the user and return them might be useful, but wouldn't a function to return a single value from the user be ever more reusable?

Comment: typo, you have extra `*` in make_tuple.

Comment: Note: `std::tuple` may be replaced by `std::pair`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm new to programming if it isn't obvious. :P